# angular custom filter issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement custom filter in angular js. The idea is that user can add some tags and each time filter is invokes.

**Filter** is a plain javascript object, basically it looks like this:

```
var filter = {color:'blue', length: 15};
```

**Items** are array of objects.

```
app.filter('filterByTags', function () {
    return function (items, filter) {
        debugger;
        if (!isEmpty(filter)) {
            var filtered = items;
            for (var prop in filter) {
                if (filter.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
                        if (filtered[i][prop] !== filter[prop]) {
                            filtered.splice(filtered.indexOf(filtered[i]), 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            alert('Return filtered items');
            return filtered;
        } else {
            alert('Original items ');
            return items;
        }
    };
});
```

So if works fine when i add tag but when i remove this tag i should get  **initial items list**, but i get already filtered list.

So for instance originally i have a list of 5 items and when i click some tag I should get 4 items. But when I remove this tag i should get 5 items again, but i still get 4 items.

I think it is because in this line of code:

```
return function (items, filter) {
```

when filter invokes second time, items are already filtered and returned list before. Any ideas how can i fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.  What happens if you clear your cache in between runs?

Comment: You can use `ngTagsInput` module. It is very powerful and you can extend it with your needs. Just google it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the synergy of the following 2 lines:

```
var filtered = items;
...
filtered.splice(...);
```

You see `splice` alters the array; but the array already points to the original `items`, meaning that the original items array is being altered!

The solution is to make a shallow copy of the array; instead of the first line above, do:

```
var filtered = items.slice(0);
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but in my scope i will always have whole items array and on my view will be render filtered array, how can i check if filtered is empty to show user message about it? I guess i dont have any access to filtered variable, thanks in advance